# setcookie to vue app show on the request but not in the app

Tags: php, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, setcookie

I have a front in vue and a back in PHP.

I'm trying to set a cookie but it's not working Chrome recognises the cookie but doesn't save it.

The front is http://192.168.1.17:8080
and the back is http://192.168.1.17

I perform a post like this:

```js
guest
  .post("/user/login", formData, {
  auth: {
    username: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
  headers: {
    "access-control-expose-headers": "Set-Cookie",
  },
})
```

I set the cookie like this:

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.17:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Expose-Headers");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
setcookie('my_cookie', 'cookie_value', time() + 3600, '/', '', false, false);
```

the result of the request:

[image: netwok tab show the cookie]

but here nothing is set:

[image]

Sorry if i'm not very clear.

I want to be able to send back the cookie (withCrendtial: true)

I find something similar here but gave me nothing may be missed something:
[Cookies missing in Chrome dev tools application tab but visible under network section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111195/cookies-missing-in-chrome-dev-tools-application-tab-but-visible-under-network-se)

Comment: Not sure what exactly `guest.post` is, but assuming it is some AJAX/fetch thing, the withCredentials flag would need to be set, for the browser to _accept_ cookies across different origins.